# angular 5 dialog box close is not working in IE

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

angular 5 Dialog box close is not working in IE-Edge and IE-11.
I try with below code. It's working fine in chrome and safari.

```
<mat-icon class="close-icon" (click)="handleDialogClose()" >close</mat-icon>
```

and

```
handleDialogClose() {
        this.dialogRef.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are importing `MdDialogRef` in your code,

For example,

```
import {MdDialogRef} from '@angular/material';

export class YourClass implements OnInit {
   constructor(public dialogRef: MdDialogRef<ModalComponent>) {}

   handleDialogClose() {
       this.dialogRef.close();
   }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: yes, i have added. but forgot to add,



`import { MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material;`